# Watermark in a TextBlock

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to make a watermark appear inside a TexBox, I have done this with the Canvas tag:

```
            <Canvas Height="60" Width="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5">
            <TextBox Width="500" Height="30" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" FontSize="18"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="whereAreyouWatermark" Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Top="7" Height="30" FontSize="16" 
                       Foreground="#777777" Width="500">
                <Run x:Uid="text2"></Run> <Italic FontSize="13"><Run x:Uid="text3"></Run></Italic>
            </TextBlock>
        </Canvas>
```

However, now when the cursor goes over the textblock it's not the "I" icon, just a normal pointer.  In CSS, I would change the cursor like this "pointer: text".

How can I do this in XAML?

Also, when pressed I want focus to go to the background textbox, I take it the best way is to just intercept the gotfocus event of the textblock and pass focus in-code to the textbox.  I think in iOS you can use a layer which simply passes through events.

thanks very much
Much obliged to ya, as we say all the time in London ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by watermark? Text that's inside the textbox when you click the text is gone like websites text boxes?

Comment: yep, that's right. So overlay a textblock and style the textblock in such a way that the IBeam cursor is still retained on mouse over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend having a look at the [WinRT XAML Toolkit's WatermarkTextBox](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16885#310525).

Answer (score 0):

Set the default text to something and once it got focus event, clear the text with whatever the user types. And when it's LostFocus place the watermark again. Your IBeam cursor will not be a problem with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution would be to set some default text (which will serve as a watermark) to the TextBox. On GotFocus event, clear the text from code behind. On LostFocus event, check whether if the user has entered some text or the TextBox is empty. If it has some user text, let it be. If it is empty, place back the watermark text!